# Matlab: select elements of vector conditionally

Tags: matlab, octave

I would like to get a list with all files in a directory

```
 d=dir(pwd); # get a struct of all elements (including folders)
```

now i would like to select all element of d.name, where d.isfolder=0

```
 jj=1;
 for ii=1:numel(d)
   if d(ii).isdir==0
     filelist{jj} = d(ii).name;
     jj+1;
   end
 end
```

Is this possible without a loop?
I think there should by a way to vectorize this operation

i'm working with matlab/octave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a loop, you can do this with indexing

```
isDirIdx = [d.isdir];
names = {d.name};
fileNames = names(~isDirIdx);
```

Comment: I needed the list of the files instead of the folders

      isFileIdx = [d.isdir]==0;
      names = {d.name};
      FileNames = names(isFileIdx);